# Autostart Plugin with Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way to start a plugin (e.g. Selenium IDE) with Firefox?

I'd like to open Firefox and the plugin simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the commandline argument "-chrome" for firefox.

For Selenium IDE the Command was:

```
firefox -chrome chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide.xul
```